# NWebsec CSP for Google Analytics on ASP.NET -> How to include all Google domains

Tags: asp.net, google-analytics, content-security-policy, nwebsec

We are using NWebsec on our IIS ASP.NET webseite. All fine and dandy, but maintaining all the Google domains for Google Analytics is a bit a pain. It seems that for every country that a user is, a different Google domain is used:

```
        <connect-src self="true">
          <add source="www.google.com" />
          <add source="www.google.de" />
          <add source="www.google.en" />
          <add source="www.google.com.br" />
        </connect-src>
```

Now, obviously we could just try to add as many of them as possible, but that is very cumbersome. Have not tried a Wildcard for the top-level domain, but to me `www.google.*` seems like opening the floodgates for bad domains like `www.google.ihackyou.com`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a list provided by Google https://www.google.com/supported_domains

Comment: Was hoping for some wildcard solution, but I guess that works too